# (T-SQL) Insert Multiple Records to Table re-using Sub-Queried Foreign Key for each

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a maintainable Insert Script for a project, which includes several tables having Foreign Key Relationships.  I have the following Tables in this scenario:

```
TABLE [dbo].[VehicleMakes]
[VehicleMakeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[VehicleMakeDesc] [varchar](50) NOT NULL

TABLE [dbo].[VehicleModels]
[VehicleModelID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[VehicleModelDesc] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[VehicleMakeID] [int] NOT NULL
```

For brevity's sake I excluded the Foreign Key Constraints etc, as I am interested in the query logic for allowing me to take this:

```
INSERT INTO VEHICLEMODELS (VehicleModelDesc,VehicleMakeID)
Values
('FLHTC', (SELECT V.VehicleMakeID from VehicleMakes as V where V.VehicleMakeDesc = 'Harley-Davidson')),
('RoadKing', (SELECT V.VehicleMakeID from VehicleMakes as V where V.VehicleMakeDesc = 'Harley-Davidson')),
('Softail', (SELECT V.VehicleMakeID from VehicleMakes as V where V.VehicleMakeDesc = 'Harley-Davidson'))
```

and have a group of Models that are all inserted, reusing the same Foreign Key subQuery for Make (as opposed to just copy/pasting this for each one)

Comment: It's Not really clear from the question - are you inserting to both tables? If so, are you inserting multiple records to both, or just to the `VehicleModels` table?

Comment: This is for inserting to just the one table - the other table has no Foreign Key relationship(s) so its a much simpler insert (think of *VehicleMakes* as a ***Lookup*** Table)

Comment: Well, in that case, Hadi's answer is correct. Please note, however, that when you're using an identity column as your primary key, you still have to enforce uniqueness on your table's natural key. For more information, read [SQL Server’s identity column misconceptions](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/sql-servers-identity-column-misconceptions) over on my blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just store the `MakeID` within a variable and using it in the insert query:

```sql
DECLARE @MAKEID INT

SELECT @MAKEID = VehicleMakeID from VehicleMakes where VehicleMakeDesc = 'Harley-Davidson'

INSERT INTO VEHICLEMODELS (VehicleModelDesc,VehicleMakeID)
Values
('FLHTC', @MAKEID ),
('RoadKing', @MAKEID),
('Softail', @MAKEID )
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `VALUES` statement, this would work better as a series of `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...` statements, like this:

```
INSERT INTO VEHICLEMODELS (VehicleModelDesc,VehicleMakeID)
SELECT Descr, MakeId
FROM (
    SELECT 'FLHTC' as Descr, (SELECT V.VehicleMakeID from VehicleMakes as V where V.VehicleMakeDesc = 'Harley-Davidson')
UNION
SELECT 'RoadKing', (SELECT V.VehicleMakeID from VehicleMakes as V where V.VehicleMakeDesc = 'Harley-Davidson')
UNION
SELECT 'Softail', (SELECT V.VehicleMakeID from VehicleMakes as V where V.VehicleMakeDesc = 'Harley-Davidson')
```

Also, if you are only going to insert rows for the same make in one statement, this can be modified to use CROSS JOIN logic:

```
INSERT INTO VEHICLEMODELS (VehicleModelDesc,VehicleMakeID)
SELECT VehicleModelDesc, VehicleMakeID
FROM (
    SELECT 'FLHTC' as VehicleModelDesc
    UNION
    SELECT 'RoadKing'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Softail'
    ) as Models
CROSS JOIN (SELECT V.VehicleMakeID from VehicleMakes as V where V.VehicleMakeDesc = 'Harley-Davidson')
```

Comment: Although I'm not clear on why `union` is better than `values`, I'll suggest that `union all` doesn't involve adding the overhead of a sort pass to remove duplicates.